# QuickFIX Position Report Resend Request

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I am sending Position Report by using VeriFIX application, and it is working totally fine that I can interact with the 'acceptor'.

However, I found that when 'Resend Request' is required, indeed it does resend the Position Report, the problem is some tags are missing, due to that reason it is failed to resend that Position Report.

Here is what I receive from the message:

> Message Definition Validation: Missing required tag(s) - PosMaintRptID(721) PosReqResult(728) ClearingBusinessDate(715) NoPartyIDs(453) AccountType(581) SettlPrice(730) SettlPriceType(731) PriorSettlPrice(734) NoPositions(702) NoPosAmt(753) PosAmtType(707) PosAmt(708)

Actually I did set those values before sending Position Report, and they are simply gone when comes to 'Resend Request'.

I have no ideas why is that happening, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Paste the fix messages, you sent and received from the logs. Your message is totally useless and shouldn't be the place to check for  errors.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, your application written using QuickFIX/J is sending a Resend Request to the VeriFIX application to have the VeriFIX application resend the Position Report. The VeriFIX resends the Position Report to your application but QuickFIX/J does not accept the Position Report, claiming it is missing tags... In that case there would be a problem with VeriFIX and you probably better contact support for that product.